# Gnome's calculator: "Malformed expression"

Tags: gnome, calculator

I can't calculate a simple math expression `1.3e4 * 10` in the Gnome's calculator in scientific mode, I just get *"Malformed expression"* warning below the number pane. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome calculator would prefer to see

`1.3x10^4 * 10`

A shortcut to do this is to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, as in

<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>

This can be found in the calculator application help menu, under 'scientific notation'

Comment: I wonder why it is not intuitive as it's supposed to be?, it works though.

Comment: @Jim-chrissCharles The notation that you used does work elsewhere, like in the LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet, and I would have used it myself!  Gnome Calculator is useful to me for short, small calculations but not much that's more complex.

Comment: @Jim-chrissCharles It's very intuitive if you're familiar with LaTeX, but I agree it feels like a strange design choice *not* to support the e-style notation.

Comment: @undercat I knew I recognized it from somewhere - but it's been several years since I did serious work with LaTeX